# SQL Server Express conection string

Tags: sql-server, entity-framework-core, connection-string

I'm trying to connect to a local SQL Server Express database using EF Core with this connection string:

```
"Server=(localdb)\\WIN-R84DEUE96RB\\SQLEXPRESS;Database=rmcsql;Trusted_Connection=True"
```

I get this error:

> fail: Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Database.Connection[20004]
>
> An error occurred using the connection to database 'rmcsql' on server '(localdb)\WIN-R84DEUE96RB\SQLEXPRESS'.
>
> fail: Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Query[10100]
>
> An exception occurred while iterating over the results of a query for context type 'RMC_IEM.DataStore.EF.ApplicationDBContext'.
>
> Microsoft.Data.SqlClient.SqlException (0x80131904): A network-related or instance-specific error occurred while establishing a connection to SQL Server. The server was not found or was not accessible. Verify that the instance name is correct and that SQL Server is configured to allow remote connections. (provider: SNI_PN11, error: 52 - Unable to locate a Local Database Runtime installation. Verify that SQL Server Express is properly installed and that the Local Database Runtime feature is enabled.)

[image]

What is wrong with this connection string?

Comment: Why do you have `(localdb)\\ ` at the start of that connection string?

Comment: Try removing `(localdb)`: `Server=WIN-R84DEUE96RB\\SQLEXPRESS`

Comment: You can choose between either LocalDB or SQL Express, they don't combine. If the database lives on your own machine, I suggest using `.\SQLEXPRESS`.

Comment: I use (localdb)\\ because  server and  db  on local machine

Comment: "Server=WIN-R84DEUE96RB\\SQLEXPRESS;Database=rmcsql;Trusted_Connection=True"

thats  works,  thank you so much guys!

Comment: Again: if your SQL Server is on the same machine, use `.` instead of the actual machine name